# url_for migration to Flask Restful

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I had my Flask routes defined like this:

```
@api_app.route('/api/1.0/infrastructure/', methods=['POST'])
def create_infrastructure():

     return (jsonify({'job': job_instance.reference}), 202,
                    {'Location': url_for('get_job', ref=job_instance.reference, _external=True)})
```

get_job function:

```
@api_app.route('/api/1.0/job/<string:ref>', methods=['GET'])
def get_job(ref):

        job = Model.Job.query.filter_by(reference=ref).first()
        if not job:
            abort(400)
        return jsonify({'job': job.reference})
```

I migrated to a flask.ext.restful environment and now looks like this:

```
from flask.ext.restful import Resource
    class Job(Resource):
        def get(self, ref):
            job = Model.Job.query.filter(Model.Job.reference == ref).first()
            if job:
               return jsonify(job.serialize())

            resp = Response(status=404, mimetype='application/json')
            return resp
```

In this class based API using flask.ext.restful
**How to define the url_for parameters in this class based environment?**

In my main app file:

```
api.add_resource(Job, '/api/1.0/job/<string:ref>')
imbue_api.add_resource(Infrastructures, '/api/1.0/infrastructure')
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to just use [flask-restful's `Api.url_for`](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.Api.url_for).

So instead of writing

```
url_for('get_job', ...)
```

You would have to

```
from flask_restful import Api

Api.url_for(Job, ...)
```

*Note:* 
It is important to make sure you don't create circular imports by importing classes into each other. My personal preferred way to organize this is to import all involved resouces in the `__init__.py` and then if you want to link to them you `import .Job`, that way you enforce a clean import order.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I used the following:

```
from flask import current_app
api = restful.Api
```

In my Infrastructure class:

```
response.headers['Location'] = api.url_for(api(current_app),
                                                           Job,
                                                           ref=job_instance.reference,
                                                           _external=True)
```

And works fine now